# Sort array of objects using multiple date properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've this Array of objects:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    timestamp1: Date,
    timestamp2: Date,
    timestamp3: Date
 },
 {
    id: 2,
    timestamp1: Date,
    timestamp2: Date,
    timestamp3: Date
 }.
 ...
]
```

I want to sort the array by newest Date comparing all 3 object properties and using the newest one for each object.

Tank you very much in advance.

Comment: Sort the array of objects by date. Use the max date value from 3 dates while sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the js `sort` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) you'll see that sort is taking a function as parameter which :

- Return **a positive integer** if the first object is *bigger* than the second one
- Return **0** if the two objects are the same
- Return a **negative integer** if the first object is *smaller* than the second one.

Knowing that, let's build the function together :

First, we'd like to get the highest date for on object.

For that, i would recommend using [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) which takes an array and returns the biggest parameters.

Here it works because js understand date as integers.

```js
function highestDate(obj){
   return Math.max(obj.timestamp1,obj.timestamp2,obj.timestamp3)
}
```

Now let's build the sort function.

```js
function compare(a,b){
   return highestDate(b) - highestDate(a)
}
```

here is a snipper for testing :

```js
function highestDate(obj){
   return Math.max(obj.timestamp1,obj.timestamp2,obj.timestamp3)
}


function compare(a,b){
   return highestDate(b) - highestDate(a)
}

let obj1={
  id:1,
  timestamp1 : new Date(2001,1,1),
  timestamp2 : new Date(2002,1,1),
  timestamp3 : new Date(2003,1,1) //third highest date
}

let obj2={
  id:2,
  timestamp1 : new Date(1997,1,1),
  timestamp2 : new Date(2004,1,1),//second highest date
  timestamp3 : new Date(2003,1,1) 
}

let obj3={
  id:3,
  timestamp1 : new Date(1991,1,1),
  timestamp2 : new Date(2001,1,1),
  timestamp3 : new Date(2005,1,1) //highest date 
}

let arr = [obj1,obj2,obj3]

console.log(arr.sort(compare))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can find the maximum timestamp for each object using Object.values and Math.Max.

Creating a function to find these values `getMaxTimestamp`, we can use this in array.sort() to sort the objects by the maximum timestamp:

```js
 
const arr = [ { id: 1, timestamp1: new Date('2021-07-01T16:00:00Z'), timestamp2: new Date('2021-03-01T08:00:00Z'), timestamp3: new Date('2018-10-08T19:00:00Z') }, { id: 2, timestamp1: new Date('2019-08-01T16:00:00Z'), timestamp2: new Date('2015-09-21T08:00:00Z'), timestamp3: new Date('2017-10-08T19:00:00Z') }, { id: 3, timestamp1: new Date('2024-01-01T16:00:00Z'), timestamp2: new Date('2015-09-21T08:00:00Z'), timestamp3: new Date('2021-10-08T19:00:00Z') } ]

function getMaxTimestamp(obj) {
    const timestamps = Object.values(obj).filter(v => v instanceof Date);
    return Math.max(...timestamps);
}

const result = arr.sort((a,b) => { 
    return getMaxTimestamp(a) - getMaxTimestamp(b);
})

console.log("Result:",result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and try the comparison functions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property). There would be some tweaking involved while finding the max date should be easy to do if you just look around with a simple google search.